# How to make text closer to the input radio tag?

Tags: html, css

My css for radio input tag:

```
.radio-label-type {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
.block-radio {
  width: 50px;
}
```

Then, in my form, I have radio input tags:

```
<div class="radio-label-type">
   <input class="block-radio" type="radio" name="nodeType" id="topic" value="topic" > topic </input>
   <input class="block-radio" type="radio" name="nodeType" id="author" value="author" > author </input>       
</div>
```

The 'topic' and 'author' words are next to the radio input tags, but they are at a short distance. How can I adjust their distance to make the text much closer to the radio tag?

Comment: remove ``width: 50px;``

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using `margin-right` in your CSS.
Like This:

```html
<div class="radio-label-type">
   <input class="block-radio" type="radio" name="nodeType" id="topic" value="topic" > topic
   <input class="block-radio" type="radio" name="nodeType" id="author" value="author" > author
</div>
```

```css
.radio-label-type {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
.block-radio {
  width: 50px;

 /* Add this to decrease the text and radio button spacing*/

  margin-right: -20px;

/* To increase the distance  */
/* margin-right: 20px        */
}
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trojan14/k5dsnput/)

Comment: Strange that in my case, margin-right doesn't effect. I inspected it and found that the margin-right:-20px was cancelled out by something else. How to fix that? Also, I had a color:red in .block-radio and it didn't effect too, although inspection shows that it was cancelled out.

Comment: It might be cancelled out because another `margin` property is overwriting the `margin-right`.

Comment: There is no other margin in this block-radio. There are other margin, like margin-buttom in other styles. How to deal with this?

Comment: can u show proper code in JSFiddle

Answer (score 1):

Generally input tags don't have closing tag so you should wrap with a div.

```css
.radio-label-type {
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .block-input {
      margin-inline:20px ;
  }
  .block-input input{
      margin-inline: 15px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="radio-label-type">
    <div class="block-input"><input class="block-radio" type="radio" name="nodeType" id="topic" value="topic">topic
    </div>
    <div class="block-input"><input class="block-radio" type="radio" name="nodeType" id="topic" value="topic">author
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply target input type and set space what you want.

```css
input[type="radio"]{
  margin-right: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-label-type">
   <input class="block-radio" type="radio" name="nodeType" id="topic" value="topic" > topic </input>
   <input class="block-radio" type="radio" name="nodeType" id="author" value="author" > author </input>       
</div>
```